# How to get a list of all packages that a .NET solution ACTUALLY requires?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clr

Suppose I have a large .NET solution consisting of multiple projects. Each of these projects has some NuGet dependencies. These direct dependencies will also have some transitive dependencies but it's possible that the project in question doesn't actually need that transitive dependency.

Eg:

Package A:

```
public class A() {
    
}

public void DoSomething() {
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public B CreateB() {
    return new B();
}
```

Package B:

```
public B() {
     ;
}
```

If I have just 1 project in my solution that only uses `A.DoSomething()` and never calls `A.CreateB()` and also does not directly reference Package B, then even though B is a transitive dependency for my solution, it's not actually needed.

Is there some existing tool that helps me get a list of all packages that are actually needed by my solution?

I have a product which I ship through an installer. I often miss including transitive dependencies in the installer and as a result, the application fails at runtime.

Comment: How do you create an installer and what is the target of .net that your application runs ?

Comment: If you "often miss including transitive dependencies in the installer" then it seems the list of nuget packages you obtain is incorrect, not that you are getting the "full" list and shipping too many / unused ones.

Comment: It's a very different question whether you're trying to not include stuff that's not actually required vs making sure that you get all the transitive dependencies. What is your preference?

Comment: @J.Memisevic For the installer I have .wixproj files and I manually specify within these proj files the list of assemblies and files that I want to include in the installer. Currently its .NET 4.8 but I am in the process of migrating it to .NET 6.

Comment: @PMF I would want an answer for both of the questions if possible, maybe I should edit the title of the question?

Comment: @PMF As I mentioned in another comment, the list of files that I want to include in the installer is maintained manually (so I don't "bloat" the installer and ship unnecessary files). I think this is completely wrong approach but then I don't know whats the right way.

Comment: That approach isn't completely bad, but I would rather make sure that the application doesn't reference stuff it's not using and then you can just go with the "whatever is referenced is needed" approach. Of course, you could go with one of the modern AOT (ahead-of-time) compilers, but these are very much in beta only.

Comment: Well the way I see it - your installer should contain everything that is  inside your folder when you do release. Same as  applications do deploy via pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting task and I think here is no simply answer (or maybe I don`t know it)

As for me solution will looks like external code analyze tool, previously i wrote something like this use Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/

This package it`s different reflection and you can use it for find information about every single line of code in your project.

So you need to:

- get all classes
- get all methods in all classes
- get all lines of code in all methods
- filter line, get only lines that have other methods call
- get all namespaces that this methods have
- group by namespaces

after that you can match really used namespaces and nuget packages and which of them really used

Here is code example how you can do this:

```
  var usedNamespaces = AssemblyDefinition //class from Mono.Ceccill nuget package
    .ReadAssembly("path to your dll") // assembly reading
    .Modules
    .SelectMany(m => m.Types) //get all types
    .SelectMany(t => t.Methods) //get all methods
    .Where(m => m.Body != null) //ignore abstract methods
    .SelectMany(m => m.Body.Instructions) //get each line of methods code
    .Distinct() //ignore the same
    .Where(i => i.Operand != null)
    .Where(i => i.Operand is MethodReference) //get only that lines that call some other methods
    .Select(i => (MethodReference) i.Operand)
    .Select(r => r.DeclaringType.Namespace) //get used methods namespaces
    .Distinct() //ignore the same
    .ToList();
```

This is just example you can upgrade it for your needs, but its works
[image]

Comment: That won't help, because it only does a static analysis. The OP wants a dynamic usage analysis (e.g. not include a dependency from a method that's never called). Also, I believe this is very expensive even for medium-sized projects.